# Function not found in Mocha\Karma Test

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js, karma-runner

I have a simple class defined in file A that looks like this:

```
var canSendTestEmail = (function(){
    'use strict';
    return{
        sendTestEmail: _sendTestEmail()
    }

    function _sendTestEmail(){
        //do something
        return null;
    }
})
```

File A is located in the same folder and is being loaded properly via Karma config

I use this class in a Mocha test that is quite simple.  The test looks like this:

```
 describe('canSendTestEmail', function(){
    'use strict';
    describe('should send an email', function(){
        expect(canSendTestEmail.sendTestEmail()).to.equal(null);
    });
});
```

I am testing an Angular application using Karma as a test runner.  Chai, Sinon and all of the usual suspects are loaded properly.

When running my test, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'canSendTestEmail.sendTestEmail()')
```

I have tried all sorts of ways to define the class canSendTestEmail and no matter what I either get type cannot be found or the error above.

I think I am missing something obvious here.  I come from a C++ and Java background so this may be a javascript "thing"

What is wrong?

My question has been answered!  I will post my update code later.

Comment: I forgot to add that I know that File A is being loaded into Karma correctly

Comment: `canSendTestEmail.sendTestEmail` is undefined, and you are trying to run it as a function...

Comment: Changed my code to this and now get an error saying that canSendTestEmail can't be found.

`(function(){
    'use strict';
    function canSendTestEmail (){
    }

    canSendTestEmail.prototype.sendTestEmail = function(){return null;}

})()`

Comment: `canSendTestEmail` is a function, a not resolved function, this is, you defined it, but didn't run it ( think as a pointer to a C++ function ). Then you try to get a property of it, which in javascript is quite fine... As this is valid: `(function () {}).sendTestEmail`, in which returns `undefined`. Then you try to execute undefined, and then you get your error.

Comment: I guess I am struggling with why it is not being resolved as I have written code like this in Javascript many times in the past few months and have never seen this.

How would you implement the function?

Comment: The most easy fix is to make `canSendTestEmail` as a IIFE, this is, a self invoking function like this -> `(function () { })()`, notice the parens at the end of the declaration. The result of the function will go to the `canSendTestEmail` variable.

Comment: Problem solved.  Thanks joaumg!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the class definition.

The working version is something like this:

```js
var canSendTestEmail = (function(){
    'use strict';
    return{
        sendTestEmail: _sendTestEmail  // (problem 2) notice no parenthesis here
    }

    function _sendTestEmail(){
        //do something
        return null;
    }
})()  // (problem 1) notice parenthesis here
```

First, as mentioned in the comments to the question, is that `canSendTestEmail` is a function which returns an object.

So the `canSendTestEmail.sendTestEmail()` statement tries to call the `sendTestEmail()` method of the function and not the method of the object created by this function.

This is actually the same as doing something like this (can be tested in browser javascript console):

```js
var func = function (){}
func.sendTestEmail()

VM510:2 Uncaught TypeError: func.sendTestEmail is not a function(…)
```

Second problem, is that function `_sendTestEmail` is actually invoked in the object definition, so we will get an object like `{sendTestEmail: null}` - `sendTestEmail` is null and not a function.

Comment: Not sure how to mark this as answered.  I arrived at the solution described above with the a nod in the right direction from @joaumg.

Comment: @JasonGuarracino then maybe it is good then to ask joaumg to add his comment as a reply and you can accept it